# changing colours of the specific parts of matplotlib chart on hover

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to create a function that colour part of the chart in different colour when we hover mouse above a single value (for example part of the chart between hovered index and hovered index + 3) without creating a lot of Series objects and setting visibility of each sub-chart?
Below I attach picture with desired state.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import pandas as pd

x = [x for x in range (0, 20)]
y = [random.random() for x in range (0, 20)]

x = pd.Series(x)
y = pd.Series(y)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o-', color = '#336699')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you use *x* in the comprehension list for *y*, you change its value.

Comment: You can pretty easily hook to `motion_notify_event`, find the nearest data point, and then re-plot it and the three points following.  I assume you've looked at https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/users/event_handling.html